# Downloading files, setting cookie expiry SPOIDCRL

Tags: sharepoint-online, my-site, site, download

I'm looking to download multiple files from a SharePoint site and upload them to another cloud provider. I've done some testing and it looks like I only have to add the cookie to the cookie container on the HttpWebRequest. When setting the cookie expiry date

```
Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30)
```

The download throws a 403 which is expected. I was hoping I could set for it for 5 days.
I guess the question is, is there max expiry date that can be set for the SPOIDCRL cookie? Will I need to re authenticate at any point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [SharePointOnlineCredentials class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharepointonlinecredentials.aspx) from [SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038) the *expiry date* for authentication cookie (`SPOIDCRL`) should be set to `1 hour`

The following example demonstrates how to provide `SPOIDCRL` HTTP header in order to perform request authentication in SharePoint Online/Office 365:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endpointUri);
var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName,securePassword);
var authCookie = credentials.GetAuthenticationCookie(webUri);
request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, authCookie);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You mention should be set to 1 hour, I can't see the reference to this?. Or is 1 hour  good practice. From the tests I am running with just the authCookie added as a header I can set the expiry date to a great value.

Comment: May be i wasn't clear enough, i just analyzed the specified SDK with Reflector and found that expiration date for authentication cookie is set to 1 hour. So, you'll probably not find it in official documentation.  I would say this is a default value (or good practice) and not the maximum one.